# How to reference a student report (semester report)?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, citing, back-referencing

There are some institutions where undergraduates/bachelor students may submit reports (e.g. project reports) at end of a semester. Say, I want to refer to such a report using a `bibtex` or `biblatex` entry. The only thing so far I found in use is on [Master or semester project reports (en:output:student_reports [Algo])](http://algo.epfl.ch/en/output/student_reports), where it seems they use the `unpublished` entry type (example [here](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/export.py?recid=138789&fm=bibtex)).

Is there maybe a more appropriate entry type than `unpublished`, that would work in either `bibtex` or `biblatex`, respectively? I wouldn't go with `article` or `inproceedings` because that implies publishing, nor with `misc` (I use that for plain webpages already) - but would, say, `techreport` be appropriate, or is there something better? Note that I'd also want to note a URL (and possibly URL date), and institution.

Here is also a "pseudo" entry as an example:

```
@????{cite-key,
  author = {John Dough and Jane Doe},
  title = {An example of some basic analysis},
  submissiondate = {2013/01/22},
  year = {2013}, % based on submissiondate
  urldate = {2014/04/10},
  url = {http://example.com/2013/example_semester_report_12.pdf},
  note = {3rd semester project report},
  institution = {Dept. of Something, University of South Nowhereton},
}
```

Comment: If you're using biblatex, use `@online` for webpages. Besides there's no reason you can't use `@misc` for both reports *and* webpages, it's supposed to be a catch-all.

Comment: Why don't you use the `unpublished`-type?

Comment: Also the `thesis`-type should be right. Take a look in the biblatex-manual, `2.1 Entry Types`. There all entry types are explained. There's also a irregular type `mathesis` (MA-thesis) – you could try to create your own type `bathesis` and use `mathesis` as its model.

Comment: @sdaau I would rather use `Techreport`. Seems appropriate when following-up on previous work. Plus, you can still add the `url` field.

Comment: @Nicolas Why would that make `@techreport` appropriate?

Comment: Thanks for the nice tip, @NajibIdrissi ! You're right there's no reason (at least technical) why I shouldn't use `@misc`, but I'd sort of prefer the description of the type of citation to be in the entry type (which is why I'd also prefer `@online` in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @musicman - I didn't consider `thesis`, because these sort of reports would be "below" (in rank) from even a bachelor thesis (which in itself is a "requirement for a degree"), and so I'd rather keep them separate.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Nicolas - didn't think of `techreport` at all; that seems appropriate, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that thesis type is right. The following shows two possibilities. Incidentally, your date format was wrong, but I've corrected it: you need to divide dates with hyphens not slashes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{thesis,
  author = {John Dough and Jane Doe},
  title = {An example of some basic analysis},
  submissiondate = {2013/01/22},
  date = {2013}, % based on submissiondate
  urldate = {2014-04-10},
  url = {http://example.com/2013/example_semester_report_12.pdf},
  type = {3rd semester project report},
  institution = {Dept. of Something, University of South Nowhereton},
}
@misc{misc,
  author = {John Dough and Jane Doe},
  title = {An example of some basic analysis},
  submissiondate = {2013/01/22},
  year = {2013}, % based on submissiondate
  urldate = {2014-04-10},
  url = {http://example.com/2013/example_semester_report_12.pdf},
  note = {3rd semester project report},
  institution = {Dept. of Something, University of South Nowhereton},
}
% note: `type` is "commented" below, to show that "Tech. rep." is inserted
% by default for techreport, even if `type` is not explicitly set.
% to overload, uncomment the type, and set needed value.
@techreport{techreport,
  //type = {Tech. rep.},
  author = {John Dough and Jane Doe},
  title = {An example of some basic analysis},
  submissiondate = {2013/01/22},
  year = {2013},
  urldate = {2014-04-10},
  url = {http://example.com/2013/example_semester_report_12.pdf},
  note = {3rd semester project report},
  institution = {Dept. of Something, University of South Nowhereton},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[type=thesis, title={Using Thesis Type}]

\printbibliography[type=misc, title={Using Misc Type}]

% note: for some reason bibtex will parse the above @techreport
% into just {report} in the .bbl; so use "report" here to select!
\printbibliography[type=report, title={Using Techreport Type}]

\end{document}
```

[image: test1.png]

Comment: Many thanks for that answer, @PaulStanley - I was a bit worried that these reports have a lower "rank" than a thesis; and so I added the `techreport` to your answer as an alternative - hope that's OK. Cheers!

Comment: Btw how did you compile it? I tried `pdflatex test.tex`, got `Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s): test`, ran `bibtex test`, and got `You're missing a field name .. % based on submissiondate .. I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry`, meaning `bibtex` broke at that comment (which resulted with shortened output in pdf). Only after removing those comments from the code fully, did it compile as in [your image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h1k7l.png).

Comment: @sdaau Thanks, that's a helpful change. I compiled it using biber, and got no warnings (though afaik submissiondate is ignored).